# Power BI - Add column using M to count 2 years of data

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have 2 years of data on a bar chart and an x-axis that I created by concatenating Year and Month Number into a separate column called "Year - Month"

```
Number.ToText([Year]) & Number.ToText([Month Number])
```

The result is

```
20171
20172
20173
20174
...
201711
201712
20181
20182
20183
20184
20185
...
```

How can I create a calculated column in M to add a number column that counts 1 - 24 which will allow me to sort the x axis on the chart?

Also how can I make this dynamic allowing any new data in the report to auto increment to 25, 26, 27... into year 3?

Answer (score 1):

Try in Power Query editor:

Go to > Add Column > Index Column > From 1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you're asking for, but you might prefer to create a date column that you could use for your axis instead.

```
= #date([Year],[Month Number],1)
```